# How to convert `complex sql` into `typeorm` statement?

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

### Question

How to use `where in` in `typeorm`?

This paragraph is the sql I wrote. I hope to convert this sql into a typeorm statement, but I am not sure how to deal with `WHERE IN`.

```sql
SELECT
    mytable.councillor,
    first_join_time,
    latest_state,
    member_term_count,
    proposal_count,
    approved_count
FROM "mytable" "mytable"

    left join (select councillor, timestamp as first_join_time
       from mytable
        where timestamp in (select min(timestamp) from mytable group by councillor)
        ) join_time
    on mytable.councillor = join_time.councillor

    left join (select councillor, state as latest_state
       from mytable
        where timestamp in (select max(timestamp) from mytable group by councillor)
        ) state
    on mytable.councillor = state.councillor

    left join (select councillor, count(*) as member_term_count
       from mytable
       where state = 'Member'
       group by councillor) member_term
    on mytable.councillor = member_term.councillor

    left join (select proposer, count(*) as proposal_count
       from council_proposal
       group by proposer) "proposal"
    on "mytable"."councillor" = "proposal"."proposer"

    left join (select account, count(*) as approved_count
       from council_proposal_vote
       where approve = true
       group by account) approve
    on mytable.councillor = approve.account

group by
    mytable.councillor,
    join_time.first_join_time,
    state.latest_state,
    member_term_count,
    proposal_count,
    approved_count;
```

### My failed trying

I ran into a few problems,

1. How to set the name of the field that needs to be displayed (only the content I set is returned)
   I set select because I only want a few fields that I want, but in the end he returned all the fields.
2. How to add where in statement, which seems very cumbersome.

```js
this.createQueryBuilder('mytable')
  .select(
    `
      mytable.councillor,
      "join_time"."first_join_time",
      "state"."latest_state",
      "member_term"."member_term_count,
      "proposal"."proposal_count",
      "approve"."approved_count"
    `
  )      
  .leftJoinAndMapOne(
    'mytable.councillor',
    (subQuery)=> {
      return subQuery.select('councillor, timestamp as first_join_time')
        .whereInIds('timestamp in (select min(timestamp) from mytable group by councillor)')
        .from(CouncilCouncillor, 'mytable');
    },
    'join_time',
    'join_time.councillor = mytable.councillor'
  )
  .leftJoinAndMapOne(
    'mytable.councillor',
    (subQuery)=> {
      return subQuery.select('councillor, state as latest_state')
        .whereInIds('timestamp in (select max(timestamp) from mytable group by councillor)')
        .from(CouncilCouncillor, 'mytable');
    },
    'state',
    'state.councillor = mytable.councillor'
  )
  .leftJoinAndMapOne(
    'mytable.councillor',
    (subQuery)=> {
      return subQuery.select('councillor, count(*) as member_term_count')
        .where("state = 'Member'")
        .groupBy('councillor')
        .from(CouncilCouncillor, 'mytable');
    },
    'member_term',
    'member_term.councillor = mytable.councillor'
  )
  .leftJoinAndMapOne(
    'mytable.councillor',
    (subQuery)=> {
      return subQuery.select('proposer, count(*) as proposal_count')
        .groupBy('proposer')
        .from(CouncilProposal, 'council_proposal');
    },
    'proposal',
    'proposal.proposer = mytable.councillor'
  )
  .leftJoinAndMapOne(
    'mytable.councillor',
    (subQuery)=> {
      return subQuery.select('account, count(*) as approved_count')
        .where('approve=true')
        .groupBy('account')
        .from(CouncilProposalVote, 'council_proposal_vote');
    },
    'approve',
    'approve.account = mytable.councillor'
  )
  .groupBy('mytable.councillor')
  .addGroupBy('"join_time"."first_join_time"')
  .addGroupBy('"state"."latest_state"')
  .addGroupBy('"member_term"."member_term_count"')
  .addGroupBy('"proposal"."proposal_count"')
  .addGroupBy('"approve"."approved_count"')
  .getManyAndCount();
```

Comment: There are no IDs in `whereInIds('timestamp in (select min(timestamp) from mytable group by councillor)')`; it should be `where('timestamp in (...)')`.

Comment: Thank you, and why can't this select specify the fields I want?

Comment: I think you'll need to separate each SELECT item to a string in an array: `.select([ 'mytable.councillor', '"join_time"."first_join_time"', ... ])`

Comment: I tried it again, but it still failed. The sql select I saw in debug looks like this `selct *, join_time.*, . . ., 'mytable.councillor', '"join_time"."first_join_time"', . . . `

Comment: I don't know what causes my `select` to be unable to specify a fixed field.

Comment: If you are selecting from multiple tables, you should `.getRawMany()` rather than `.getMany()`.

Comment: I would start by simplifying the query. Remove all the aggregating subqueries, replace them by window-functions. (BTW the `WHERE xx = (select MAX(xx) ...)` is pathological)

Comment: Do not do it at all. Once you have a query that works and can be further optimized and refactored then use it as raw. A typeorm statement would make things ugly and cryptic just to end up with the same or worse query.

Comment: Sorry, my sql writing may be a bit complicated, I want to ask what this pathological refers to? What will happen to him, and what should I replace him with?